# Facebook-connect demo - is "Callback URL" == "Connect Callback URL"?

Tags: facebook

I'm starting to feel stupid. I'm following the Facebook-Connect demo "The Run Around".

At the point when I navigate to http://www.[mysite].com/testing/register_feed_forms.php to register the one-line story, I get the following error:

```
Error while setting up application: 
You need to configure your callback URL in the Facebook Developers App
```

However, when I edit my app settings in the http://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php page, I CAN'T FIND ANY BOX TO PUT THE CALLBACK URL !!

Where is it?

What is it that I'm missing? I have found many references that it should be in the "Basic" tab of my App Settings, but I can't find it! Is it the **Connect Callback URL**?

To be more specific, this is the content I see in 'Basic':

```
Essential Information
    Application Name
    Application ID
    API Key
    Secret

Basic Information
    Description
    Icon
    Logo
    Language
    Developers

Contact Information
    Developer Contact Email
    User Support Email

User-Facing URLs
    Help URL
    Privacy URL
    Terms of Service URL
```

Thank you... Either docs are obsolete or I'm becoming slow...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "Connect URL" and a "Callback URL" are two different things, though they often contain the same url value.  Does that make sense?

And yes, the documentation is BEYOND horrible and completely unacceptable.  What's worse is that because it is so outdated, it often suggests things that will BREAK an already working app.

Just horrible...

Here's how to set your connect url.
Login as you to facebook.
Go to facebook.com/developers
You'll see somthing along the right side that says "my applications".  Click on your app.
Then click "edit settings."
You'll be taken to a new inteface that has tabs running vertically along left side.  Click the tab that says (surprise) "Connect"
The connect url text input box will be the very first at the top.

Answer (score 3):

If the 'callback url' you're talking about is the same as the 'Canvas Callback URL' that I'm thinking about, which is the only callback url that I know about, then it's the second text field in the 'Canvas' tab of the editor.  This is mine:

Canvas Callback URL: http://localhost/     Facebook pulls the content for your application's canvas pages from this URL.